# gcc: fail sanity check error, I suppose due to cxx USE flag missed

Tags: gentoo, gcc

Recently I've done `emerge -e world` and then found that `gcc` was compiled without `cxx` flag. Now I can't compile any C++ package due to

```
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

I'm thinking on copying files returned by `equery f gcc|grep -v share`
 from stage3. Will it help? Is there any simpler way?

**UPDATE 1**
Here's my [config.log](http://pastebin.com/MaHyg5bq)

**UPDATE 2**
Here's my [make.conf](http://pastebin.com/s0sjU7eL)
Please, note there's `cxx` flag in USE. I've added it recently, but it does not help as I can't rebuild packages.

**UPDATE 3** I have tried to reinstall gcc-4.6.3 from binary package via

```
emerge -avK gcc:4.6
```

It completed successfully but error didn't go.

Also, I've noticed that:

```
configure:11955: /lib/cpp  conftest.cpp
cpp: error: conftest.cpp: C++ compiler not installed on this system
configure:11955: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "expat"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "expat 2.1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "expat-bugs@libexpat.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
```

Looks like it claims that C++ compiler is not installed on my system. But this sounds like rubbish, since `gcc:4.6` was installed from bin-package and I assume it's compiled with C++ support.

**UPDATE 4** Indeed there's a problem with g++

```
uhradio ~ # g++ queue.cpp 
gcc-config: error: could not run/locate 'g++'
uhradio ~ # cpp queue.cpp 
cpp: error: queue.cpp: C++ compiler not installed on this system
```

The output from `gcc-config -l` is:

```
[1] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-4.6.3 *
```

Comment: What does `which g++` say? Run the command from update 4 with `-v`, so it tells you exactly what it is trying to do, and hunt down the programs it is trying to run. I believe your diagnosis is correct, you didn't build GCC with C++ support, that's all.

Comment: Did you add the CXX flag inside or outside of the chroot?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-294108-start-0.html) is probably what you're looking for. In short, install the kernel headers and you should be set.

Comment: `linux-headers-3.6` was installed, problem still persist

Comment: This being the case, I'd go with a reinstall, with /home and the important files (e.g. make.conf) backed up. In terms of time spent, you are probably better off.

Comment: that's absolutelly impossible as this is remote box. This system is fresh and clean but only `fails sanity check` is my issue.

Comment: Please paste your make.conf as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although `emerge -avK gcc:4.6` didn't help I've manually extracted `gcc-4.6.3.tbz2` into `/` directory then set `gcc-config 1` and it helped (although my `/usr/lib` has gone after that operation, I've manually symlinked it back to `/usr/lib64`. Now I'm rebuilding both gcc's (4.5 and 4.6) with `cxx` USE flag.

My quesion now turns into another one. What's the reason `cxx` USE flag gone from my system built from stage3? I'm installing gentoo linux for years and never explicitly set `cxx` USE flag like now.

Comment: You really need to reinstall... the CXX flag is inherited from the profile using `eselect profile`  If you never set the profile, you're going to spend more time repairing damage than using the system.

Comment: I just noticed this, but why are you slotting `gcc:4.6` when the currently supported slot is [from 11 to 13](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-devel/gcc)? Anything below 8.5 is unsupported and out of date.